# 'Button' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, eslint

[image]

These ESLint errors happen with components imported from React Native Paper imports since Expo upgrade from SDK 43 to 45. The project is able to run though.

```
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';
```

There seem to be no ESLint errors in the import.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please could you add some more of the code surrounding <Button />.

Comment: @ourmaninamsterdam This error happens in all files with all these components, where there were no ESLint errors before the upgrade

Comment: If you're using Typescript, perhaps your @types  for react-native-paper need updating to a newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in package.json

```
"resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "<version-of-react>"
},
```

More info [here](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/2965)

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping the Button component in  fragments like this : <> </>